# VIIRS products georeferencing

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing

Can anyone tell how to reproject VIIRS products (interested VNP09 and VNP14IMG) into standard projection and reference system? I managed to process some of products like CLDMASK_L2 and even VNP14 (750 m) using SNAP and HEG tool. But some of products cannot be processed in the mentioned software despite of georeferencing metadata.

Comment: HEG: HDF-EOS to GeoTIFF Conversion Tool https://wiki.earthdata.nasa.gov/display/DAS/HEG%3A++HDF-EOS+to+GeoTIFF+Conversion+Tool

Comment: HEG is good for MODIS products but, unfortunately, HEG cannot process several VIIRS products.

Answer (score -1):

One alternative is to download the fire data from the [FIRMS Archive Download page](https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/download/). This data is already converted to a WGS84 projection instead of the raw sinusoidal format - see https://earthdata.nasa.gov/faq/firms-faq#ed-nrt-standard.

Comment: Why the downvote? This data is exactly what the OP is requesting...